# Can I System.load native lib contained in a different apk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

AFAIK each android app is installed with its own user permissions. If app *A* contains native libs (i.e. `/data/data/com.app.A/lib/libA.so`), can I use `System.load("/data/data/com.app.A/lib/libA.so")` from app *B*?

On the devices I have, `/data/data/com.app.A/lib/libA.so` has others-read permissions set so I'm able to load it from another app. But is this valid on all android systems?

Comment: For the record, the proper Android way to expose functionality from one package to another is building a `Service` and sending intents to it (or binding to it). You can even designate it as in-process to avoid the IPC penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that, even if it's technically possible, this should be highly discouraged. Android doc is not clear on this, but the security policy assigns a user ID to each app such that app A cannot interfere with app B other than through the Android framework.

The only exception I can see is when the 2 apps are signed by the same key, e.g. by the same developer.

Therefore, loading the native lib of an external app shouldn't be allowed and it wouldn't be surprising if in future versions of Android the others-read permission is removed.

Not sure what should happen when one app is actually a library project, like in the case of OpenCV Manager. In that case App A is compiled together with App B (containing the native lib) and the System.load() is performed by App B's code , even if executed in App A's runtime process. (comments on this are welcome ;) )

Answer (score -1):

Even if you are able to load it because of the permission you won't be able to execute the functions inside the libA.so because it has different function signature related to package name and Class name defined in  app  **A**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_android_A_class_method(JNIEnv *d, jobject e, jstring f)
{
//some action

}
```

Hence no harm done even if you are able to load it from another app B.

Comment: Actually that's not the case. libA.so is not a JNI wrapper. I can keep the libA.so wrapper in app B and still be able to use it. The question was more about permission and android standards...

Comment: Yes, you can if you have the wrapper.
The answer was oriented towards case where app do not have the wrapper and load the lib file as you mentioned.

Comment: [@Sunny Kumar Aditya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/941864/sunny-kumar-aditya): there is no rule that all Java classes in appB must use the package declared in appB manifest. Same for appA. So, the two may use a third package name for the JNI functions, or they may both use the package of appA, or of appB. To make the things even more complicated, you can provide Java_OnLoad() public function in your native library, and bind the same methods to whatever package you choose at runtime.

Comment: @AlexCohn using a third package name is possible , I am not sure about Java_OnLoad() in native library can you please provide me some relevant link for that.